# PHP How Do I Get Value From A For Loop Used To Create Menu Options

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a form I've created sticky.

I used a for loop to create some lengthy select options, but it can't seem to figure out a way to make it sticky.

Here is one of the loops I've created:

```
    <p>Ave. Speed: <select name="speed" id="speed">
    <option value="">Speed</option>
    <?php //Print out speed
    for ($s = 70; $s <=105; $s++) {
    print "<option value=\"$s\">$s
    </option>\n";
    }
    ?>
    </select></p>
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: What you mean by *sticky* here ?

Comment: What error you exactly getting ?

Comment: i think sticky means that once you submit it, and get an error, it prefills it next load. i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of assumptions here, i.e. you are using POST to send your form data and no processing has been done on `$_POST['speed']` yet. Check whether the value of `$_POST['speed']` posted matches the value of `$s` and then use `selected` in your `option` tag:

```
<p>Ave. Speed: <select name="speed" id="speed">
<option value="">Speed</option>
<?php
//Print out speed
for ($s = 70; $s <=105; $s++) {
echo "<option value=\"$s\"";
if($_POST['speed']==$s){echo' selected="selected"';}
echo">$s</option>\n";
}
?>
</select></p>
```

Comment: Thanks JBES I did try your suggestion, and $s has a vaule of one more than the last in the loops which happens to be a value of '106'

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected a typo that will have broken the code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
    <select name="speed" >
            <option value="">Speed</option>
            <?php //Print out speed
            for ($s = 70; $s <=105; $s++) {
                echo "<option value=\"$s\"";                    
                if (isset($_POST['speed']) && $_POST['speed'] == $s){
                     echo 'selected="selected"';
                } //end if
                echo ">$s</option>\n";
            }

            ?>
            </select>
```

I just needed to check for 2 conditions. One for the option selected, and the other equal to the temporary variable.